# Replace Values in Oracle DB with set of test data

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am currently working on a project where I have a copy of a production Oracle database with some production values that I want to replace with a set of test values (with the assumption that I have more production records than test ones and I will have duplicates).

Here is a sample of what I am looking to do:

[image: Data Set Sample]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe use MOD(rownum) to match rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to number the rows by their `rowid`, then use a modulo operation to match the original data to your test data table, like this:

```
merge into customer c
using (
    with cte_customer as (
        select rowid xrowid, mod(row_number() over (order by rowid)-1,(select count(*) from test_data))+1 rownumber
        from customer
        order by rowid
    ), cte_testdata as (
        select row_number() over (order by rowid) rownumber, first_name, last_name, email
        from test_data
        order by rowid   
    )            
    select c.xrowid, t.last_name, t.first_name, t.email
    from cte_customer c
    left outer join cte_testdata t on (t.rownumber = c.rownumber)
    order by c.xrowid
) u
on (c.rowid = u.xrowid)
when matched then update set
    c.last_name = u.last_name,
    c.first_name = u.first_name,
    c.email = u.email
```

Comment: Given that the current table and the test table contain completely different data isn't this massively over-complex? Why not delete the data currently in there then add the data that needs to be in there?

Comment: @Ben Well, I guessed that @Jeremy only gave us a part of the table structure. The way my `merge` solves the task, other columns in the table would remain untouched. In the data warehouses / ETL world, obfuscating data like this is not an uncommon task.

Comment: Thomas, I think your approach may work. But I have more records in the "customer" table than the "test" table. My assumption is what was written above will only update the amount of records stored in the test table.

Comment: And yes, this is only a small part of the table, there are many other columns that are important, but do not contain sensitive data that I am looking to mask.

Comment: Fair enough, if he's only given part of the DDL with the requirement that the data in columns not described remain then this is pretty much the only way of doing it... you wouldn't need the ORDER BYs, which will do an unnecessary sort

Comment: Nope, it should work no matter the amount of data in your customer table, since it is using the `mod` to "spread" the test data to your original rows.

Comment: Damn I was just working up a very similar answer! :-)